# Combine tables into one master (merge by rows)

Tags: spotfire

I have two identical tables one for with pull from our internal system and one which is the same with manual data.

I want to merge these two into one in spotfire, enabling me to have one *MASTER' to work from.

My issue is that when I use the Add rows function, and change the manual table in my raw data and hit refresh it wont get updated

How can I ensure that when I refresh my spotfire data it takes date from both tables and do the merge?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the connections are set to Always New

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.11.6/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire_bauthor-consumer_usersguide/GUID-DCD8848B-708B-44C2-A156-39FAFA70DD3B.html